# How do i randomize words in a captcha

Tags: html, unix, captcha

I already have a code for my form but I have no idea how to randomize words so that even if you type in the wrong woRd in the captcha it generates another word. Any idea on the code to use?

Comment: Do u mean to set a "word" become "rowd" "rwod" etc?

Comment: Don't generate your own captcha, they are going to be easy to bypass. Better use reCaptcha

Comment: Yes something like that

Answer (score 1):

Use the following function to generate random string of any length

```
function randomStringGenerator($length = 10)
{
    $chars = array_merge(range(0, 9), range('a', 'z'), range('A', 'Z'));
    shuffle($chars);
    $code = implode(array_slice($chars, 0, $length));
    return $code;
}
```